# How to make an asynchronous return a promise chain within render() with componentDidMount()?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, es6-promise, web3js

I have a button within my return in my render function that calls a function that initiates a promise chain which the result updates a state variable. However, the value is not passed through.

I tried some attempts on componentDidMount() but haven't had any luck

Here is the button within my render function

```
<button onClick={this.addIPFSItem} className="btn btn-info btn-sm m-1">NewFile</button>
```

This calls the following function

```
addIPFSItem(){

var searchAddress = "0x9Cf0dc46F259542A966032c01DD30B8D1c310e05";

const contract = require('truffle-contract')
const simpleStorage = contract(SimpleStorageContract)
simpleStorage.setProvider(this.state.web3.currentProvider)


this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
  simpleStorage.deployed().then((instance) => {
    this.simpleStorageInstance = instance

    return this.simpleStorageInstance.getLength(searchAddress);
  }).then((accountLength) => {
    
    var items = []
    const ipfsPrefix = "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/";

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < accountLength; i++) {
      var currHash = this.simpleStorageInstance.getBook(searchAddress, i, 
  {from: searchAddress});

      var currURL = ipfsPrefix + this.currHash;

      //Here I am printing the counter values, and it prints the correct 
      //amount
      console.log('itemhash ', i)
      items.push(currHash)
    }
    //I do not get the value of items[1] in the console, but an undefined
    //promise
    console.log('address URL ', items[1])

    //the state of ipfsHash is not updated correctly
    return this.setState({ipfsHash: items[1]});
  })
 })
}
```

Essentially, I am executing a promise chain (by connecting to web3) and retrieving data. I think the essential problem is that I am calling an async function within the render(). I'm not sure how to fix this with componentDidMount()

`console.log('address URL ', items[1])` should give something like `address URL 0x9Cf0dc46F259542A966032c01DD30B8D1c310e05`. However, I instead get `address URL Promise{<pending>}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `this.simpleStorageInstance.getBook` is a promise, that means it is executed asynchronously.

To get it's result you either have to use `.then` or the new syntax `async/await`. With the following function your `items` array will be filled with the correct data :

> You will have to put the `async` keyword before your parent function name if you choose this solution

```
for (i = 0; i < accountLength; i++) {
    items.push(await this.simpleStorageInstance.getBook(searchAddress, i, { from: searchAddress }))
}
```

An even shorter syntax would imply using your raw array of accounts and `map` it instead of using its length :

```
const items = myAccounts.map(async () => await this.simpleStorageInstance.getBook(searchAddress, i, { from: searchAddress }))
```

Comment: Yes, `this.simpleStorageInstance.geBook` being a promise was the main problem. I just used a promise chain in the for loop for each item

Comment: Oh alright, glad it helped. If you want to greatly improve performance by making every call simultaneously, I suggest using Promise.all : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all